# Logging an array entry in different lines in the terminal

Tags: javascript, console.log

I need to log the entries in an array in different lines. Like a dropdown menu(trying to make one)
For example

The array:
`var options = ['Java', 'Python', 'JavaScript', 'C++', 'Go']`

The output:
`Java Python JavaScript C++ Go`

Tried searching online but no results.

Comment: `console.log(options.join("\n"))`?

Comment: Is this [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)? Logging array items in different lines has very little in common with making a dropdown menu.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a forEach loop like this.

```js
var options = ['Java', 'Python', 'JavaScript', 'C++', 'Go']
options.forEach((el) => {
  console.log(el);
})
```